# Unable to connect to BitBucket via SSH key

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket

I seem to be unable to connect to bitbucket via SSH, from my Ubuntu machine, no matter what I tried.

1. I created my new SSH key:

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
2. I copied the key content:

   `cd ~/.ssh`

   `cat id_rsa.pub`
3. I added the content to my BitBucket account.
4. I configured the trusted host keys in the known_hosts, as mentioned on BitBucket blog:

   `ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org && curl https://bitbucket.org/site/ssh >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
5. I added the key to the SSH Agent:

   `ssh-add ~/id_rsa`

And that's it.

`ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` hangs indefinitely.

I spent an entire day trying to make this work and I couldn't find a solution.
And yes, I tried almost anything I could find about this on Stack and BitBucket blog and so-called tutorials.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` could be useful too.

Comment: `ssh -T git@altssh.bitbucket.org -p 443`

Comment: How long did you wait for? It could take a few minutes IIRC for a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.
I had to edit the `~/.ssh/config` file and add `ProxyCommand ncat --proxy-type http --proxy 192.168.x.y:8080`

The complete guide is here: https://adangel.org/2020/10/15/github-behind-proxy/